# What does "flush with left margin" mean?

Tags: style

The MLA handbook says, "In the body of the paper, headings should be flush with the left margin, not indented or centered. For readability, include a line space above and below a heading."

What does "flush with the left margin" mean?  Does it mean to add a few cms to the left margin between a heading and the left border of a page?

Also what does "flush" mean?

Comment: [definition 4b1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flush), "directly abutting or immediately adjacent: such as  (1) : set even with an edge of a type page or column : having no indention".  So it means **don't** add any space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambridge Dictionary offers [this definition of **flush**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flush):

> **at the same level as another surface:**
> *I want the light fittings to be flush with the ceiling.*

By default, all the text in a word-processing document will be **flush** with the left margin. The most common alternative alignment is centered text, which you use for your title and the heading of your "Works Cited" section.

Your instruction describes headings that should be flush with left margin—that is, perfectly aligned with most of the essay's text. Don't center it and don't indent it.

> **A Flush Heading**
> some text
> some text
> some text

> **An Indented (or Centered) Heading** 
> some text
> some text
> some text